# Specify default value in case of an empty nodeset

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Using XPath 2.0, how can I specify a default value in case of an empty node set? I'd like to be able to do something to the tune of `$datatypes/type[@key="somevalue"] or "default value"` to have *default value* be returned if the key is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is not what you are looking for, but I think what you need to do is to have a  [Conditional Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-conditionals).

Therefore try something like this:

```
if ($datatypes/type[@key="somevalue"])
 than $datatypes/type[@key="somevalue"]
 else "default value"
```

Comment: I also found out that ```($datatypes/type[@key="somevalue"], "default value")[1]``` is another way as well (and a bit shorter!).

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: This only works for single result nodes. XPath flattens sequences instead of nesting, so in case of multiple matching elements you'd only get the first one. For sequences of arbitrary length, stick to @hr_117's answer.